# Cannot create valid state with payload for reducer from ngrx documentation

Tags: ngrx

I have problem to update state in `ngrx` reducer for action `loadSuccess`

State after `load` action

```
{
  dashboard: {
    serverList: null,
    isLoading: true,
    error: 'zero'
  }
}
```

State after `loadSuccess` action

```
{
  dashboard: {
    isLoading: false,
    error: 'zero'
  }
}
```

```
const t1 = (state, action) => {
  return ({...state, serverList: action.payload.servers});
};

const reducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(load, state => ({...state, isLoading: true})),
  on(loadSuccess, (state, {servers}) => ({...state, serverList: servers})),
//  on(loadSuccess, t1)
);



export function dashboardReducer(state: State | undefined, action: Action) {
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

when I swap `on(loadSuccess....` line with `t1` state it works. I actually check what the object in parameter is and fetch value what I want. But why it fails for `on(loadSuccess, (state, {servers}) => ({...state, serverList: servers}))`?

Actions definition

```
export const load = createAction('[Dashboard Component] Load');
export const loadSuccess = createAction('[Dashboard Component] LoadSuccess', props<{servers: ServerInfo[]}>());
```

Answer (score 0):

should you share how you define the `loadSuccess` action?

looks like you have the `payload` property and should use it as `payload.servers`.

Comment: added actions definition

Answer (score 0):

2nd Parameter of the given function contains the action, not the payload..

```
 on(loadSuccess, (state, {payload}) => ({...state, serverList: payload.servers})),
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answer with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @daddykom I tried this. I got  an error with {payload} and its partially compiled. Its like I see as html output what I want but there is an error. After removing {} I have same issue. State has no data

Comment: Ok. Try this: on(loadSuccess, (state, action) => ({...state, serverList: action.payload.servers})), Do you have the brackets around the curly brackets?

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem came from ngrx docs, from the definition of effect.

```
@Injectable()
export class MovieEffects {

  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private moviesService: MoviesService
  ) {}
}
```

Action here is defined as `{ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies }`

After change to use directly defined above action `export const loadSuccess = createAction('[Dashboard Component] LoadSuccess', props<{servers: ServerInfo[]}>());` it works

```
loadSomething$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(DashboardActions.load),
    mergeMap(() => this.service.getServers().pipe(map(servers => Actions.loadSuccess({serverList: servers})))),
    catchError(() => of({type: '[Dashboard Component] ServerInfo Loaded Error'}))
    )
  );
```